# UrlFetchApp.fetch timeout error after 1min depending on environment

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, timeout, urlfetch

I have an apps script that takes data from a spreadsheet, sends it to an API and prints the results in another sheet. This app is published in the marketplace and some of the users, not many are getting timeout errors around the 1 min mark. This value does not correspond to the timeout in the [GAS quotas](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) which is around 5-6min.

The code is the same for all the users, the data sent in the request does not seem to change the behavior, and it happens against different endpoints (of the same API).

The only thing I'm able to see in the logs is that UrlFetchApp.fetch is throwing a timeout exception, but I haven't been able to debug it any further.

This is the request:

```
  try {
    response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
      'muteHttpExceptions': true, 
      'method': 'post', 
      'payload': params
    });
    if(isJson(response)) {
      json = JSON.parse(response);
      status = json.status;
    } else {
      if(response == '') {
        // api did not respond
        json = JSON.parse(mocked_response_with_error);
        status = json.status;
      } else {
        //rollback spreadsheet creation
        return;
      }
    }
  } catch(e) {
    console.error('User "'+ params['key'] + '" obtained the following exception in ' + service + ': '+ e);
    showException(e);
    return;
  }
```

The logs viewer for the project shows me the following error:

*"User "user_key" obtained the following exception in [service]: Exception: Timeout: url"*

Any ideas on why this is happening or what else I could test? As it does not happen for every environment, I haven't been able to reproduce it in mine.

ETA: the code is an [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/) as opposed to code developed/run in the [App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/).

Comment: UrlFetch() do not have specific timeout from my experience, for me the issue is must on API side, do you log some exception on your servers when API is invoked ?

Comment: Could it be that your Urlfetch app has a [shorter timeout](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/appref#urlfetch_timeout)?

Comment: @St3ph the APIs return specific errors if something goes wrong (I'm part of the APIs development team, the script is an integration with those APIs) so I don't see how anything on that side (the APIs return a json) could end up as an exception in the integration...

Thank you!

Comment: @Jescanellas I'm going to check that link in depth in case I see something that can help, but if it's a timeout associated to Urlfetch, shouldn't it happen to every user? Unless it's something configurable for each account?

Comment: @BlancaGalego maybe those users have some specific configuration which causes this. Could it be that the other requests (the good ones) take less than a minute? Is there any way you can know this?

Comment: @Jescanellas I was just checking out the link you shared, but from what I've seen it refers to Java code running in Google's App Engine. The issue I'm facing is using Apps Script (*.gs files, which is basically JS) for the development of a Google Sheets add-on.

I have managed to run processes longer than 1min in my environment as well as had users hitting the timeout defined in the GAS quotas (the 6min one).

The only thing I can think of is something related to browser settings or the google account itself, but I haven't been able to figure it out. Thanks for your input!